# Loading dynamically generated content after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Google Instant style search script written in jQuery. When a user searches, a URL is created which is something like #search/**QUERY**/1/. However, when you either reload the page, click a result which goes to a different page or return back from a previous page the search results are no longer there. Why could this be?

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&category=web';
        window.location.hash='search/'+query+'/1/';
        document.title=$(this).val()+" - My Search Script";
        if(search==''){
            window.location.hash='';
            document.title='My Search Script';
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                if(response !=""){
                $("#result").html(response);
                } else {
                $("#result").html("No results were found.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /// Your original key up here...

    // With browser's back you should get your hash back, so you should be
    // able to fill in the query value back and simulate key release to trigger search
    if(window.location.hash.indexOf('#search/') == 0) {
        query = window.location.hash.replace('#search/', '').replace('/1/', '');
        $('#search').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because its return to the previous state of the page before the search.

Maybe this can be a workaround:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   /* 
     your code here
   */ 
   if ($("#search").val() != "")
     $("#search").keyup();
});
```

So it will mimic the behavior of when the user is searching when the page reloads, return back, etc..

Comment: Would not work on page reload. Since nothing's ever posted, I think you'd have to use a cookie or something to save the last searched value in order to make it work on reload.

Comment: If you reload a page the form wouldnt be cleared unless it has auto-complete=off attribute, so i think it should work because the keyup will be triggered anyway.

Comment: Go to most any page (e.g.) google.com, type something in the search bar and hit reload. There's nothing about the way browsers work that would persist anything typed into a form that has not been submitted.

Comment: @jamietre - Firefox tends to keep your input values after refresh, but that is most definitely not the kind of feature to rely on!

Comment: Doesn't for me in firefox! I'm just saying this from the context of the *actual* question the OP asked. Personally, I don't think you'd want to persist data entered in a form on reload -- since that's the way browsers are supposed to work. If you wanted to protect form input, instead you should handle `window.unload` and ask them.